# Send multiple users to same google hangout by link (in new window)

Tags: javascript, php, google-hangouts

I have a submit button on my website.  When it is clicked from "user A" it saves some data to DB and send an "invitation" to "user B" via ajax. (both users are looged in and online at my website)

Now I want open google hangout (in a new window) where both users will join.
So in fact how can I send both users to the same hangout by just clicking my button from my website.

Is it possible to generate a google hangout url even if nobody have joined it yet?
If this is not possible, is it possible to send "user A" to google hangout which will open the hangout (now a url should be genrated) and send the url to my website (db) so I can display the link to "user B"?
I haven't found anything about this in the net, so I hope someone can help me here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have done the same thing in one of the projects I've worked on before. Essentially, you can silently have User A join a hangout, get that URL and invite User B to that hangout session.

Comment: @BasitSaeed How do you get that URL?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But my question is, how can I achieve this? How can a let User A open the hangout and send the url to my server so I can show the url to User B

Comment: @blex I did that a long time ago. I'm gonna have to find the project I achieved it and take a look at the code.

Comment: Have a look at this
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#inviting_people_to_the_hangout

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a Hangout app.

To have the app automatically launched when the user clicks the Hangout button, add your app_id to initial_apps parameter of the button.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-rr"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-rr', {
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
    'widget_size': 175
  });
</script>
```

or launch it directly

```
https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/?gid=<app_id>
```

From within the app, you have to use gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl() function to get the URL of the Hangout. Send that url using ajax

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm now sending the user to my app and send the url using ajax.

But I now have another problem.  The second user who joins the hangout by the url which have been send by ajax, doesn't start the app automatically.  how can I do this? I need to send both users  to the same hangout + launching the same app.

Comment: The second user must also open the hangout link with the query paramter https:/.......?gid=<app_id> to start the app automatically

Comment: On Google Developers Console, `app_id` is called `Project Number`. On the old console, it's `Project ID`.